# Using variables for simple python commands

Tags: variables, python-3.5, declaration

Im sorry I know this is really stupid question, but I'm having a hard time passing a variable through simple python commands. I'm coming from BASH so I would simply use $ to solve this.

```
module = input("Enter module name: ")

import module
content = dir(module)
print (content)


exit (0)
```

How do I let python know "module" is a variable here?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a python library called `importlib` to do such a task

The sample code is given below

```
import importlib
module_name = input("Enter the module to be imported: ")
imported_module = importlib.import_module(module_name)

print(imported_module.getcwd())
```

Here I was importing the `os` library for demonstrating how the imported library would work and print it's output directly